# Heroku error: We're sorry, but something went wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

i have deployed an app to heroku(finance tracker under "ROR developer course" from udemy.com). The login button works fine but when i click on the signup button, it gives me this error

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

I have ran heroku run rake db:migrate successfully.
I used devise gem for authentication.
Pls any idea someone??....thanks

Edit

From log:

```
2016-10-26T17:46:19.965045+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET   path="/users/sign_up" host=johnuzoma-finance-tracker.herokuapp.com   request_id=9b928dfe-66be-47b5-933b-3d5b6cf3a899 fwd="197.210.25.210"   dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=19ms status=500 bytes=1754
2016-10-26T17:46:19.950321+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_up"  for 197.210.25.210 at 2016-10-26 17:46:19 +0000
2016-10-26T17:46:19.955368+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by  User::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
2016-10-26T17:46:19.957892+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal  Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2016-10-26T17:46:19.958887+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-10-26T17:46:19.958889+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined  method `for' for #<Devise::ParameterSanitizer:0x007f782dff6408>):
2016-10-26T17:46:19.958890+00:00 app[web.1]:    app/controllers/user/registrations_controller.rb:7:in `configure_permitted_parameters'
2016-10-26T17:46:19.958891+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-10-26T17:46:19.958892+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-10-26T17:46:20.651597+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=johnuzoma-finance-tracker.herokuapp.com request_id=8d875ac1-de78-47 68-9cd0-a653afd2318b fwd="197.210.25.210"  dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=133
```

RegistrationsController code

```
class User::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up).push(:first_name,  :last_name)
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update).push(:first_name, :last_name)
  end
end
```

Comment: run this command "heroku logs" to check error logs

Comment: Run `heroku logs -t` and recreate the error again. The logs will give you a clue as to what is causing it. Post the logs here if you still can't figure it out yourself.

Comment: You can also install the free PaperTrail plugin to have an easy view and searching ability for your Heroku logs.

Comment: Any progress on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first thing you should do is go to the Heroku admin panel for your app and look through the log file. You should find a stack trace (should look like an error followed by a bunch of method calls and line numbers). Another option is for you to remotely access the app server, go to you Heroku app directory on your computer and run (assuming you have Heroku CLI installed)

```
heroku run bash
```

then navigate to your log directory and run

```
tail -f <replace_with_log_file_name>
```

(log file should be production.log or develop.log) and that will show you a real time stream of the log activity, so just go recreate the bug and see what happens.

Replace these lines

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up).push(:first_name,  :last_name)
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update).push(:first_name, :last_name)
end
```

With these lines

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name,  :last_name])
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])
end
```

What happened is the gem `devise` that you are using changed its API in version for so the syntax you are were using is no longer valid. I am assuming that at some point in time you did a bundle update or something that inadvertently upgraded you gem

Comment: ~/log $ tail -f <"development.log">
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Comment: O I am sorry you don't include the <> thats usually short and for a variable in documentation, though its not so universal that I should expect it be understood by everyone so my bad. Try `~/log $ tail -f development.log`

Comment: Did that but i got this:                                                                                tail: cannot open `development.log' for reading: No such file or directory

Comment: Ok while you are in your `log` directory, type in `ls` and tell me what are the names of the `.log` files in there?

Comment: only production.log

Comment: Ok than type in tail -f production.log and follow the rest of my advice and recreate the error.

Comment: did that and it took me to the root of my app like this:                              ~/log $ tail -f production.log

C:\Sites\finance_tracker>

Comment: Ok so thats my mistake, navigate to the `log` directory of your rails app not `~/log`. Then type this `tail -f production.log`

Comment: Ok type `tail -f development.log` then

Comment: did that and operation was successful as in "started get blah blah blah"...now what?

Comment: Go and do whatever caused your error in the first place and see what the error is, it should show up in that window.

Comment: when i click on signup, it gives me the same error "We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."

Comment: What does it say in the ** log file**  you are suppose to keep the console open, then click the sign up button and see what the log file says like the error message tells you `application owner check the logs for more information.`. That was the whole point of you typing `tail -f development.log`, so that when you cause the error you can see what is going on realtime on the back end.

Comment: I have edited the question, check the logs are above

Comment: Great! paste in your `registrations_controller.rb`

Comment: check above now

Comment: Um...see if it works? Also did you update it on you local on on heroku?

Comment: Sorry bro but what country are you?

Comment: I live in  the USA

Comment: would have loved to chat but dont have enough reputation

Comment: Yea I hate to clutter the comments but what else can you do, you will be there in no time.

Comment: i live in Nigeria and i need to keep in touch with guys like you....can you drop your contact on this email: bobonnaaa@gmail.com

Comment: or if you are on whatsapp send me your mobile number

Comment: Yea I will follow up with you later, but you do realize that this answer actually answers your question right?

Comment: Then why unselect? did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this much difficulty in determining error through Heroku logs one more thing you can try is you can see error on the browser itself and to do that in your `production.rb` file (which you will find in config/environments directory) change:

```
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

To:

```
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

Now deploy your app again on Heroku and you are good to go.

Comment: So effectively what this will do is allow anyone to figure out what your code is doing, and open you up to countless vulnerabilities.

Comment: vulnerabilities are far away sir...the person is even not aware of heroku logs command.